# Changing the Pagetitle colour will not take effect for the Library titles or when the page title is rendered as <a> link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, css

I have modified my pagetitle  tag style colour to be white inside my seatle.master page, using the following CSS :-

```
<h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle" style="color:white;float:left;text-align:left;direction:rtl">
  <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
              runat="server"
              RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                  SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
              CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">
        <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
          <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
        </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
      </SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
  <SharePoint:AjaxDelta BlockElement="true" id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription" CssClass="ms-displayInlineBlock ms-normalWrap" runat="server">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="ms-pageDescriptionDiv" style="display:none;">
      <span id="ms-pageDescriptionImage">&#160;</span>
    </a>
    <span class="ms-accessible" id="ms-pageDescription">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />
    </span>
    <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
      _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setupPageDescriptionCallout");
    </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
  </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</h1>
```

This will change the title colour for the home page only , but if i add a library or if I have other pages , then their titles which is rendered as  links will stay black.while the home page title is rendered as text. As shown below:-

[image]

So my question is how I can force the  link text colour which is rendered for the pages title to be white.

Comment: You'll have to incluce some CSS which will override the CSS styling for A tags in `h1.PageTitle`.

Comment: Or using !important on the color: attribute

Comment: i added the following directly to my master page <h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle" style="color:white !important;float:left;text-align:left">. but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found the solution in
[another stack post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180000/how-do-i-alter-the-css-for-a-pages-title/180039#180039)

It works if we add the *span a* extension to the css class

```
.ms-core-pageTitle span a
{
 background-color:grey!important;
 color:white!important;
}
```