# How do I alter the CSS for a page's title?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, css

I have been using an outside CSS file to change the look of our SharePoint sites.  Where I have run into an issue is changing the title font.

```
/*=============
  Title Changes
  =============*/

.ms-core-pageTitle {  
font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff !important;
background-color: #7E3B20;
}
```

Everything seems to work on all pages attached to the site, except the font settings.  It goes back to default as soon as you navigate to another page.  I think I may be missing which class I should be editing.  Does the title bar have a selector instead?

Thanks,
-Robin

**New Code After Answer**

```
/*=============
  Title Changes
  =============*/

.ms-core-pageTitle {  
text-align: center;
background-color: #7E3B20;
}

.ms-core-pageTitle, .ms-core-pageTitle a{
font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Which class do you see applied when you inspect the page with the developer tools?

Comment: Thank you Teylyn.  I just started using dev tools and did not know just how informative it was.  Between looking there and Danny's tutorial, I was able to rewrite my code to work and without the "!important" arguments.  Last time I did webpages CSS was a new thing, so dev tools on the browser is both amazing and wonderful now that I am supporting a SharePoint site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: right-click the element in the browser and select 'inspect element' to inspect the CSS in the F12 Developer console

---

CSS has **Specificity**, which is a weird word for a simple concept:

**More Specified CSS rules determine which selector is applied**

So

> The account with firstname Robin

is a selector,

and

> The account with firstname Robin and lastname Huighe

is **more specific**, and in CSS terms: **has a higher Specificity value**

In the Core SharePoint CSS the title is selected with:

```
.ms-core-pageTitle a {  
  font-family: "Segoe UI Light" ....
}
```

> The a tag inside a class .ms-core-pageTitle

Has a **higher Specificity** than your

```
.ms-core-pageTitle {  
  font-family: Calibri ....
}
```

> The class .ms-core-pageTitle

#### !important

You can break the Specificity by adding `!important` after **EVERY CSS attribute** like you have done for the color:

```
.ms-core-pageTitle {  
  font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #7E3B20;
}
```

**BUT** Not only are you making your CSS more complex, you are also breaking any other CSS rules that might be applied later.

If Web-Designers see `!important` used,
it is a tell tale sign the "Developer" does not understand **CSS Specificity**

#### increase CSS Specificity for ms-core-page-Title

[image]

Your CSS pageTitle declaration can be made **more specific** (and thus overrule the CSS that SharePoint Core defined) with:

> The a tag, **inside a span**, inside the class .ms-core-pageTitle

```
.ms-core-pageTitle span a {  
  font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #7E3B20;
}
```

This does **not** require `!important` ductaping

See: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

#### IDs have higher CSS Specificity

As you see in the screenshot above, there is another way to style the title.

Because the a tag inherits CSS from its parent(s) and IDs count for higher Specificity you can use:

```
#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea {
  font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #7E3B20;
}
```

#### Challenge

What color is applied?

[image]

```
#pageTitle a {
   color:green;
}
#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea {
   color:blue;
}
```

Answer: (mouseover)

> The #id reference give the two CSS rules the same Specificity, the last color (blue) would have been applied. But the a tag selector gives the first rule more Specificity, so the color green is applied

iCSS

Comment: That is awesome.  Thanks Danny.  After this new knowledge I have gone through most of my CSS and cleaned out the "!important"s.

Comment: You master more now than 90% of people who "know" CSS :-)